# how to display popular posts by multiple meta keys in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I want to display popular post in custom page , I have added post views and post like option in wordpress and I want to show popular posts based views and likes,

I tried this code but it's ranking only for views counter ;

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'=>5,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'meta_query'      => array(
    'relation'    => 'AND',
    '_post_views' => array(
      'key'     => '_post_views',
      'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    '_post_like_count'    => array(
      'key'     => '_post_like_count',
      'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
),
);
```

thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [new `orderby` feature](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 5,
    'meta_query'      => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        '_post_views' => array(
            'key'     => '_post_views',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        '_post_like_count' => array(
            'key'     => '_post_like_count',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        '_post_views' => 'DESC',
        '_post_like_count' => 'DESC'
    )
);
```